# How to generate dynamic Jplayer Playlist from JSON or XML url using Playlist Add-on

Tags: xml, json, dynamic, jplayer, playlist

How can I generate a dynamic Jplayer Playlist from JSON or XML or folder url and use that playlist with the new Jplayer Playlist Add-on?

The Jplayer team mentions you can do this (http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/), but show no examples yet for both how to generate a dynamic playlist and how to link that playlist to the new Playlist add-on. Would someone please show a working example of a way to generate a dynamic playlist and link that new playlist to the new Jplayer Playlist?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var cssSelector = {
    jPlayer: ".jquery_jplayer_1", 
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
};
var playlist = []; // Empty playlist
var options = {
    swfPath: "../newjs/jplayer", 
    supplied: "mp3"
};
var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options);
$.getJSON("<?php print base_path() ?>/album-json",function(data){  // get the JSON array produced by my PHP
    $.each(data,function(index,value){

       myPlaylist.add({title:$(this).attr("title"),mp3:$(this).attr("mp3")}); // add each element in data in myPlaylist

    })

});
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code as the starting point:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var cssSelector = { jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1", cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1" };
   var options = { swfPath: "../js", supplied: "ogg, mp3" };
   var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, [], options);

   $.get("xml_audio.php", {}, function (xml){
      $('Track', xml).each(function (i){
         var title = $(this).attr('title');
         var track_name = $(this).attr('track_name');

         myPlaylist.add({ 
            'title': title, 
            'mp3': 'audio/' + track_name + '.mp3', 
            'ogg': 'audio/' + track_name + '.ogg' 
         });
      });
   });
});
```

Alternatively, please take a look at [jPlayer Jukebox add-on](http://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jplayer-jukebox/). It is based on [jPlayer Playlist add-on](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/) but adds extra functionality, such as ability to scan the page for media links and make them playable. It now supports playlists in [XSPF](http://xspf.xiph.org/) format.

[image: jPlayer Jukebox add-on]